# VSCode intellisense extension for @Input() in Angular templates

Tags: angular, vscode-extensions

When referencing a custom component in an Angular template, I would like help with the props/ `@Input()`'s I've created.  Does anyone know about an vscode extension which autocompletes the @Input() properties to a component?

Coming from a react background, take this component:

```
export default function Comp(props: { text: string }) {
    return (<p>{props.text}</p>);
}
```

- When I enter `<Comp`  , I'll get autocomplete for the properties.
- When I forget a required properties, my component gets underlined and warns: `Property 'text' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ text: string; }'.ts(2741)`

I would like to have something like that in Angular as above example. I do know that angular language service somewhat brings this functionality, but it does not autocomplete anything.

Comment: "I do know that ...", then from where? If you meant the Angular VSCode extension, then open an issue to discuss with the developers, https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues